# Total Size in a Module

Tags: bash, shell, unix, size

I am trying to find the total size of the `libc.a` module using the unix `size` command.

When running it, I get a lot of different files total sizes. What is one possible way in which I can take one column of the output of 'size' (the column `dec` in this case which has the total size of the file in decimal) and add them up?

Is that possible to do in the command line?

Comment: Try `du -h libc.a` instead of `size`. If you want to get size value, `du -h libc.a | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
size libc.a | awk '{ print " " $4 " " }' | tail -n +2 | paste -sd'+' | xargs expr
```

The steps:

1. Use `size` to generate the ouput
2. Use `awk` to print the fourth field inserted between spaces
3. Use `tail` to print from the second line (ie. skip the first line)
4. Use `paste` to join all the lines, separated by a `+`
5. use `xargs` to pass the result as a parameter to `expr`.

   1. Use `expr` to add up the values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not interested in the actual file size of `libc.a`, but would like to calculate the sum of the `dec` column in the output of `size`, here is a command line:

```
size libc.a | tail -n +2 | cut -f 4 | tr -d '\n' | sed "s/^ *//;s/ *$//;s/  */+/g;s/$/\n/" | bc
```